# "No message found for this issue" when running pipeline with SonarQube

Tags: python, azure-devops, sonarqube

Currently, I am integrating SonarQube analysis for python into Azure Devops pipeline. And problem is even if the build results is mark as passed, I got the error message "No message found for this issue".

[image]

It seems not cause any problem except it looks like the build has failed...

I believe this is a bug from the SonarSource team and found a topic in their community already discussing this one, but there are no temporary work-around solutions until now....

> https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqubeanalyse-spurious-errors-in-azure-devops-no-message-found-for-this-issue/28090

So, my question is what may be causing this and is there any solution to temporary work-around this issue?

Comment: Actually, it is related to SonarSource extension. And you have to contact with that team. And this is an issue. You should add your comment under that link.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I see that they already created a ticket to fix it, And there are no work-around solutions. I've asked here to find a work-around solution since they are fixing it...